# Get page edges coordinates in Metapost and ConTeXt

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core, context, metapost

I have written several macros for my projects using TikZ. Several of them need to be aware of the page edges and margins. For example, this is a small macros I have written to draw rectangles from the current position to the edge of the paragraph. One key TikZ feature on which it depends is the ability to obtain one of the page edge's coordinates, `current page.west`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\myline{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
        \fill let \p1 = (current page.west) in
        (0, 0) rectangle (\x1 + \textwidth + \spinemargin, 0.5em);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur.\myline
    
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
    accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque 
    ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae 
    vitae dicta sunt explicabo.\myline
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to port some of my projects to ConTeXt, but I have struggled trying to replicate that piece of functionality with MetaPost. I have come across some examples where it's possible to reference the edges, but then you give up the the current position.

P.D.
There might be libraries for this concrete example, but I would like to use MetaPost for maximum flexibility since later I will have to port more complex graphics, such as arrows leading to margin notes, etc.